# How can I update minio credentials from /etc/default/minio

Tags: digital-ocean, credentials, object-storage, minio

I had create a server with a minio instance following this tutorial. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-object-storage-server-using-minio-on-ubuntu-18-04-es. All is working fine but when I change the credentials at the file in /etc/default/minio the server just crash. I restarted minio but the problem continue. Just if I change the credentials to the original credentials the server works ok.

So what can I do to change my credentials periodically for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Minio stores  "accessKey"  and "secretKey"   in "config.json" file usually located at  "/root/.mc/config.json"  or "/root/.minio/config.json"

change current accessKey and secretKey values in config.json and restart minio service.